Bereishith (Genesis) chapter 49 begins with a reference to "the end of days." Is that understood to refer to something still future?
Bereishith (Genesis) chapter 49 begins with a reference to "the end of days." Is that understood to refer to something still future?:

א  וַיִּקְרָא יַעֲקֹב, אֶל-בָּנָיו; וַיֹּאמֶר, הֵאָסְפוּ וְאַגִּידָה לָכֶם, אֵת אֲשֶׁר-יִקְרָא אֶתְכֶם, בְּאַחֲרִית הַיָּמִים.
1 And Jacob called unto his sons, and said: 'Gather yourselves together, that I may tell you that which shall befall you in the end of days.

https://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0149.htm

Yes, the most famous interpretation of this is that he gave them explanations of the coming of the Messiah. See midrashim, Ohr Hachaim etc on this pasuk.

There are several directions to interpret the verse. The basic source is Bereshis Rabba 98:2:

“Jacob called to his sons, and he said: Gather, and I will tell you what will befall you at the end of days. Assemble and hear, sons of Jacob, and listen to Israel your father” (Genesis 49:1–2).
“Jacob called to his sons.” “The lot is cast in the bosom” (Proverbs 16:33) – this is the lottery of Yom Kippur. “And all of one’s judgment is from the Lord” (Proverbs 16:33) – to determine which will be for God and which will go to an uninhabitable land.
Another matter: “The lot is cast in the bosom” – this is the lot of the tribes. “And all of one’s judgment is from the Lord” – that the Holy One blessed be He agreed with him to give each and every one as befitting him.
“Jacob called to his sons” – Rabbi Yudan and Rabbi Pinḥas: Rabbi Yudan said: Jacob called the Almighty to be with his sons. Rabbi Pinḥas said: He invited Him to his sons. Rabbi Avun said: He appointed Him steward for his sons.
“He said: Gather ….” – gather from the land of Egypt and assemble in Rameses. Gather from the ten tribes and assemble to the tribe of Judah and Benjamin. He commanded them to act with deference to the tribe of Judah and Benjamin.
Rabbi Aḥa said: Purify yourselves, just as it says: “They gathered themselves together…” (Nehemiah 12:28), “and they purified the chambers” (Nehemiah 13:9). The Rabbis say: He commanded them regarding dissension. He said to them: ‘You shall all be one assembly.’ That is what is written: “You, Son of man, take for you one piece of wood, and write on it: [For Judah] and for the children of Israel [his companions]” (Ezekiel 37:16) – it is written “his companion” – the children of Israel became a single group. Prepare yourselves for redemption. What is written thereafter? “I will render you one nation…” (see Ezekiel 37:22).

However, the one question that OP is asking only shows Yaakov's intention and failure to reveal the end of days as almost all commentaries note afterwards:

“[I will tell you] what will befall you at the end of days” – Rabbi Simon said: He showed them the downfall of Gog, just as it says: “It will be at the end of days” (Ezekiel 38:16). Rabbi Yehuda said: He showed them the building of the Temple, just as it says: “It will be at the end of days that the mountain of the House of the Lord will be established” (Micah 4:1). The Rabbis said: He came to reveal the End, but it was concealed from him.
Rabbi Yehuda in the name of Rabbi Elazar bar Avina: Two people, the End was revealed to them and was then concealed from them. They are Jacob and Daniel. Daniel – “But you, Daniel, obscure the matters and seal” (Daniel 12:4). Jacob – “what will befall you at the end of days.”
“Reuben, you are my firstborn, my strength, and the first of my potency; greater honor and greater power” (Genesis 49:3).
“Reuben, you are my firstborn” – this teaches that he came to reveal the End, but it was concealed from him. This is analogous to a king’s confidant who was passing from the world, and his sons were surrounding his bed. He said to them: ‘Come and I will reveal to you the secrets of the king.’ He lifted his eyes and gazed at the king. He said to them: ‘Be vigilant regarding the honor of the king.’ So, Jacob our patriarch lifted his eyes and saw the Divine Presence standing over him. He said to them: ‘Be vigilant regarding the honor of the Holy One blessed be He.’ The Rabbis said: So, the congregation of Koraḥ was sinking and descending, sinking and descending, until Hannah stood and prayed on their behalf: “The Lord puts to death and brings to life; He lowers to the netherworld and elevates” (I Samuel 2:6).

